# How to Eliminate Unwanted Text in an Excel Column with Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, sorting, data-cleaning

First I apologize if this question is addressed  elsewhere.
Anyway I recently downloaded an excel table with people indicating their race. So if you are Asian you checked "Asian". When I downloaded the data each cell comes with information like Checked:Asian, Unchecked: White, Unchecked: Black, etc,...
See image column highlighted in yellow.
As you can imagine I want the column to only have Checked: Asian and not the other stuff I am not interested in

Question: How do I eliminate the junk?
I tried to use text to columns feature in Excel but it kept only the first column, which I do not want because some of the checked data is in the 3rd or 4th columns. 
 I already contacted the the app web managers and the response I got was ..sorry that is the way our software works and you will just have to clean it up 
yourself[image: See Column highlighted in Yellow] Needless to say pretty #$@*&&!! up.

[Google Spreadsheet with Data: Please click the Sheet name "Race" on the Workbook[2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1esPx82oplmWyg-4GW3x1D0KKhCGAN69M/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you post some full examples as text so we can copy paste to test?  Do you want a formula or vba?

Comment: Are you familiar with VBA or Formulas? Can you include your attempt to clean this data?

Comment: No I do not know VBA but I used text to columns in excel except that it only keeps the first block of text and eliminates other items I want

Comment: You will need to copy the contents of the cell use [edit] to edit the post and paste the contents in the post.

Comment: Please do not link your workbook, many will not download it.  Instead choose one cell.  Highlight the text in the formula bar, copy that and paste it.  Then do the next few cells that way.  Or highlight many and copy  and paste into a textreader then copy paste that into the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in a blank column and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2&" UNCHECKED:",":","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[contains(.,'UN')=false]/following-sibling::*[1]")," UNCHECKED",""),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Great Scott!  It worked. That is a genius code you have there. Did you do this before?

Comment: I have done some things like this before, but not this specific pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a VBA function for you that pulls out the "Checked" piece of text. It starts by seeing if the data starts with "CHECKED", in which case it gets the text up to the start of the first "UNCHECKED". If not, then it looks for " CHECKED" (with a space), and again gets the text up to the next "UNCHECKED". It then removes the "CHECKED: " text at the start of the string.

```
Function fExtractChecked(strData As String) As String
    If Left(strData, 7) = "CHECKED" Then
        strData = Left(strData, InStr(strData, "UNCHECKED") - 1)
        fExtractChecked = strData
    ElseIf InStr(strData, " CHECKED") > 0 Then
        strData = Mid(strData, InStr(strData, " CHECKED"))
        If InStr(strData, "UNCHECKED") > 0 Then
            strData = Left(strData, InStr(strData, "UNCHECKED") - 1)
        End If
        fExtractChecked = strData
    End If
    If Len(fExtractChecked) > 0 Then
        If InStr(fExtractChecked, ":") > 0 Then
            fExtractChecked = Mid(fExtractChecked, InStr(fExtractChecked, ":") + 1)
        End If
    End If
    fExtractChecked = Trim(fExtractChecked)
End Function
```

Just paste the function into a new module, and you can then use this function just like any built-in Excel function, so if your data is in cell B1, you would type this into cell C1:

```
=fExtractChecked(B1)
```

Regards,

Comment: I have tried it many times bu i keep getting  blanks. Not sure what I am doing wrong. But I will keep trying.

Comment: OK, so you've pasted the function into a new code module? To check that the function is working, in the immediate window (accessed by Ctl+G), type `?fExtractChecked("CHECKED: White or Caucasian UNCHECKED: Black or African American UNCHECKED: Asian or Asian American")` and press return. You should see `White or Caucasian` appear. If that works, then return to the worksheet with the data, and in a blank cell, type `=fE`, and the intellisense should list this function. Double click on the suggested function, so it appears in the cell as `=fExtractChecked(`, select the cell to check, and type ")".

Comment: I am just not sure what is wrong, I pasted VBA code in module, saved it , when I type  in the blank cell the function  fExtractChecked pops up I click and enter then just blank cell.s No error message. But when I click the cell it shows there is a formula but no data.